# How does blue, yellow and orange coloured light affect photosynthesis?

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis, experiment

I've been conducting an experiment with different colored light and photosynthesis, and so far my hypothesis states that red light will grow the plant, green will slow or kill it, and white will grow it as normal.

I'm wondering what would happen with blue, yellow, and orange.

Thanks.

Comment: You know what they say, do the experiment and find out. Just remember to include controls.

Answer (score 1):

Your thought process should revolve around optimal spectrum for photosynthesis, since whether that happens sufficiently will determine the health of your plant. Just poking around, I found this [document](https://www.heliospectra.com/sites/default/files/general/What%20light%20do%20plants%20need_5.pdf).

What light will be usable for photosynthesis depends on which version of light absorbing protein is being used to capture energy from photons.

This diagram would indicate that pure yellow would be pretty ineffective for any pigment. Blue is fine, as is darker orange/red for chlorophyll A and B.

Keep in mind that a lightbulb, unless a very special one, will still have lots of other spectrum bleed.  It won't be a pure single color (even though it may look like a single color to your eye).

[image]

Another source from [Khan Academy.](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/photosynthesis-in-plants/the-light-dependent-reactions-of-photosynthesis/a/light-and-photosynthetic-pigments)  [image]